# I want to add fees in my token contract such that when someone buys my token he needs to pay some fees? any idea how to do it? below is the code:

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, bsc, fees

this is the GitHub link to sol file feel free to check it out:
https://github.com/Haris-Shaukat/Token/blob/main/Token.sol

Answer (score 0):

This is ERC20 Contract, you need to make a new contract were you can implement this logic.

Example: https://github.com/dappuniversity/token_sale/blob/master/contracts/DappTokenSale.sol

Comment: Hi thanks for this can you explain this contract a bit what its for and also as my contract is on BSC how can i implement it on my current contract?

Comment: BSC is not an issue, you can deploy a new contract with your token address.

Comment: This contract is all about your logic which you want. So if anyone will call the buy function they need to send some ETH and in return they will get token,

Comment: so i need to import this contract first in my existing BSC token right?

Comment: No, you can just directly use your contract in the new contract. You can refer to constructor in the above example.